# How to find all positive integers $(m,n)$ such that $m^2+527=8n^4$?

Tags: number-theory

How to find all positive integers $(m,n)$ such that $m^2+527=8n^4$?

I have tried $n = 3$ and $n = 4$: $(m,n) = (11,3)$ or $(39,4)$ are the two possible solutions.

However, are there any other solutions and how can I prove that these are the only solutions?

I have tried to perform modulo 3 and 4 on the equation, but in vain.

Comment: Try this: Your equation is equivalent to the equation
$$
x^2-2y^2=2\cdot527
$$
where $x=2n^2$ and $y=m$.

Comment: Thanks @boaz, do you mean $2x^2-y^2=527$?

Comment: No. Note that $(2n^2)^2-2m^2=2\cdot527$ is equivalent to you equation.

Comment: When I simplify your expression, is it $2n^4=527+m^2$ instead?

Comment: I think you mean $(m, n) = (11, 3)$ and $(39, 4)$, not the other way around.

Comment: @RaviFernando Thanks for pointing this, I will correct the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equation in the form $m^2=8n^4-527$ and multiply both sides by $(8n)^2$ to obtain    $(8mn)^2=(8n^2)^3-4216(8n^2)$.
The integer solutions with positive $Y$ for the elliptic equation $Y^2=X^3-4216X$ are obtained by SAGE simply by typing in the  two lines:

E = EllipticCurve([0,0,0,-4216,0])

E.integral_points()

From the output
$[(0 : 0 : 1), (72 : 264 : 1), (128 : 1248 : 1), (529 : 12075 : 1)]$
one sees that the solutions  for the original equation are obtained from the systems

$8n^2=72$,  $8mn=264$

and

$8n^2=128$,  $8mn=1248$.

Hence the conclusion: $(m,n)=(3,11)$ and $(4,39)$ are the only solutions in positive integers for $m^2+527=8n^4$.

Comment: @Ravi Fernando  Of course you're right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! I wonder if there is any way look for integral points in an elliptic curve (perhaps a manual approach) other than using SageMath?

Comment: @peterkung543 One can manually perform the algorithm described in *Cohen, Henri*, **Number theory. Volume I: Tools and Diophantine equations**, Graduate Texts in Mathematics  239. New York, NY: Springer, 2007.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try the algorithm in the section 8.7.4. If that's not the right chapter, just let me know.